# Car Media Player

Tags: head-unit, entertainment-system, center-console, infotainment

I have a BMW 525i 2005 which doesnt have any aux or bluetooth input. I currently use a FM transmitter to play songs from my USB to the cars speakers over FM.

The FM Transmitter doesnt have ability to play playlists and also doesnt allow me to easily switch songs etc so I was wondering if there is a better music player out there for the car.

I am aware of devices which emulate the cd changer however these cost alot of money and still dont provide the desired effect.

Essentially im looking for a media player , with a screen/ touchscreen that displays song information and maybe album art.

I have found many devices however they all have a battery and I'm not comfortable with leaving a device which has a battery in my car as sometimes it gets extremely warm in there.

I have also found these double din and single din devices however I am not in the position of switching my current head unit ( too much hassle on a BMW 5 series).

It doesnt have to be a large screen , infact I believe it would be perfect to have a 3.5 - 4 inch screen.

The device must be able to play audio over bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of choices mate. Bit silly talking about batteries when there are hundreds of thousands of navigation units out there happily sitting on the dash and in the hot, hot sun all day long. The temps that can be experienced in a vehicle is nothing compared to the internal temperature a battery can get to while in use and when recharging.
In other words battery-based players are safe enough and you can then select from a wide range of rechargeable bluetooth media players that would suit your needs perfectly. River used to make one with a touch screen I believe but even GPS navigators can do that these days.
phil

Comment: Do normal head units contain batteries? I always thought they were only powered from the car battery .  Yes there are many options if batteries are not the issue but hypothetically let's say I leave a mobile phone in my car permanently would the lithium battery not cause issues due to the heat ?